# CSS3 transform does not change an element's left position?

Tags: mobile, css, mobile-safari, transform

Can someone explain why using the following CSS code doesn't change an element's left position?

```
element {
-webkit-transform:translate3d(200px,0,0);
}
```

This does the same in a different way but changes the left position:

```
element {
position:absolute;
left:200px;
}
```

I have chosen the first method in combination with CSS3 transitions to trigger hardware acceleration on mobile Safari.

EDIT
Some clarification: it looks like transform changes the left position but if you want to get the left position with Javascript it returns 0.

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/baXDz/

Comment: Yeah, the transition works but if you try and get the left position with javascript alert(element.style.left) after the transform is done, you get just 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position transforms (aka translations) do not change the reported position of an element and this the correct behavior. When you transform an element you create a [new local coordinate system](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html) that is not reflected in left/right properties (or any other properties) since as far as the rest of the page is concerned the element is still in its original position (aka - when you transform an element, the page doesn't reflow to reflect its new position). This makes sense when you think about scales.skews etc. - the other stuff that you can do with transforms.

Update: if you want to do the heavy lifting, the currently applied transformation matrix is reported via window.getComputedStyle()

Update: someone pointed out that getBoundingBox now correctly adjusts for transforms and translations